# Unable to access UserIdentityManagementService in wso2 Identity server

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am using wso2 IS 5.1 .I have enabled the webservices access for the admin and able to access all teh webservices.But when i try to access the UserIdentityManagementService i am getting the following error

"The service cannot be found for the endpoint reference"

The service cannot be found for the endpoint reference (EPR) https://localhost:9443/services/UserIdentityManagementService.UserIdentityManagementServiceHttpsSoap11Endpoint/

Is there any configuration i need to change to enable this ??

Answer (score 0):

As defined [here](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-identity/blob/v5.0.7/components/identity-mgt/org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt/src/main/resources/META-INF/services.xml#L45) service name should be `UserIdentityManagementAdminService` , not `UserIdentityManagementService`. Change the endpoint accordingly and try.

Comment: I want to verify the confirmation code.UserIdentityManagementAdminService does not seem to have any   confirmUserAccount service

Comment: Seems like you want to use `UserInformationRecoveryService`. See the doc [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Creating+Users+using+the+Ask+Password+Option) for more information

Comment: But i am trying to just verify confirmation code without captcha.. i need enable captcha turned on for other use cases

Answer (score 0):

Following is the correct endpoint

https://localhost:9443/services/UserIdentityManagementAdminService.UserIdentityManagementAdminServiceHttpsSoap11Endpoint/

Thanks
Isura